# I have two lists of numpy array and i want them into a single list of numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

Input:

i couldn't make the two lists to a single list

```
data1=[1,2,3,4,5]
data2=[6,7,8,9,10]
for i in range(len(data1)):
    np.concatenate(data1,data2)   # This is not working
```

output:
This is the numpy array list that i need

```
Data=[[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

data1=[1,2,3,4,5]
data2=[6,7,8,9,10]

x=np.array(list(zip(data1, data2)))
#if it doesn't have to be numpy just do: 
#x=list(zip(data1, data2))
```

Output:

```py
[[ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]
 [ 4  9]
 [ 5 10]]
```